# how to fix firebase Attempted import error: 'getAnalytics' is not exported from 'firebase/analytics'

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

./src/FireBase.jsx
Attempted import error: 'getAnalytics' is not exported from 'firebase/analytics'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in React.js.

Don't forgot to config `gtag` in index.html for version 9.

Also import firebase like the following.

```
import  firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from "firebase/analytics/dist";
```